# iOS(Swift)で、Azure Notification Hubsのプッシュ通知のメッセージを取得できない

Tags: ios, swift, azure, push-notification

https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/
のチュートリアルをもとに、Azure Notification HubsのPush通知を受け取るiOSアプリを作成しましたが、メッセージを受信できません。

手順は、
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/CHANGELOG.ios.md#sdk-downloads
からiOS用SDK V1.2.4をダウンロードし、
プロジェクトのLinked Frameworks and Libariesから追加。
Swiftから使用できるようにするために、新規にObjective-Cファイルを作成し、以下のコードを追加。

AzureMessaging-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h"
#endif
```

Build Settings>Swift Compiler - Code Generation>Objective-C Bridging Headerに上記Bridging-Header.hファイルのパスを指定。

AppDelegate.swiftに以下を追加。

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let notificationHubConnectionString = "Endpoint=XXXXXXX"
    let notificationHubPath = "XXXXXX"

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        var types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
                    UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        var hub = SBNotificationHub(
            connectionString: notificationHubConnectionString,
            notificationHubPath: notificationHubPath)
        hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: nil, completion: {(error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("Error registering for notifications: \(error)")
            } else {
                println("Success registering for notifications: \(deviceToken)")
            }
        })
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        println("didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError \(error)")
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        println(userInfo.description)
        switch (application.applicationState) {
            case UIApplicationState.Active: 
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: userInfo.description, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            case UIApplicationState.Background, UIApplicationState.Inactive:
                println(userInfo.description)
            default: break
        }
    }
・
・
・
```

Apple Member CenterでPush通知用の証明書(開発用)を作成し、p12ファイルをAzureポータルにアップロード(SANDBOX用)。

Apple Member Centerでプロビジョニングファイル(開発用)を作成し、XCodeにインストール。

XCodeで、Build Settings>Code Signing>Provisioning Profise>Debugからインストールしたプロビジョニングファイルを指定(XCodeのプロジェクトのBundle Identiferはプロビジョニング作成時のiOS App IDと一致している)。

XCodeの、General>Deployment Info>Deployment Targetは8.0を指定。

設定しているNotification Hubsの接続文字列はDefaultListenSharedAccessSignatureを使用。

iPhone(iOS8.2)の実機で実行。

以上のような手順を踏みましたが、AzureのポータルサイトのNotification Hubsのデバッグからテスト通知を送信しても、iPhoneでメッセージを受信できません。

・application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken()で、エラーになっておりません
・application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError()は呼ばれていません
・通知が受信できれば、application didReceiveRemoteNotification()が呼ばれるかと思いますが、呼ばれていません
・iPhoneの設定で、アプリのPush通知は許可になっています

環境は
XCode 6.4
iPhone6 iOS 8.2
です。

他に何か足りない点があるのでしょうか？
ご存知の方、教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すいません、自己解決しました。
社内ネットワークのプロキシによってPush通知を受け取れていませんでした。
プロキシのないネットワークにiPhoneを接続しなおすことでPush通知受け取れていました。